# WordPressのショートコードで文字が変換されてしまう

Tags: php, wordpress

```
add_shortcode('pre', function($attr, $content = null) {
  return '<pre><code>' . $content . '</code></pre>';
});
```

WordPressのショートコード機能を使って、`pre` タグでシングルクォーテーションを2回入力してみたところ、ダブルクォーテーションに変換されてしまいました。

```
[pre]''[/pre]
```

投稿画面では、シングルクオーテーション2つなのに、実際に表示されるのは `”` です。どうすればこの変換を防ぐことができますか？

Comment: 表示上で変換されていると思いますが、変更するのは余りオススメしません。管理コンソール上で不具合が発生する可能性などがあるからです。それでも変更するなら`wp-includes/formatting.php`でエスケープされていると思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wordpressの`wptexturize`で変換されています。[http://wpdocs.osdn.jp/関数リファレンス/wptexturize](http://wpdocs.osdn.jp/%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0%E3%83%AA%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%83%AC%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9/wptexturize)

タグcode、preでは変換されないはずなのですが wordpressバージョン 4.9.6で確認したところ
変換されてしまったので　次のフィルータをfunctions.phpへ追加すると`wptexturize`を止めることが出来ます。

```
add_filter( 'run_wptexturize', '__return_false' );
```

指定したショートコードの時だけ`wptexturize`を止める時

```
add_filter( 'no_texturize_shortcodes', 'shortcodes_to_exempt_from_wptexturize' );
function shortcodes_to_exempt_from_wptexturize( $shortcodes ) {
    $shortcodes[] = 'pre';
    return $shortcodes;
}
```